# SQL connection string builder, initialized in two ways

Tags: c#, comparative-review

For a while now I have been using string builders in my code.  The way I currently do this is using the code below:

```
var Connection = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
Connection.DataSource = ServerNameTextBox.Text;
Connection.InitialCatalog = DatabaseTextbox.Text;
Connection.UserID = UserNameTextBox.Text;
Connection.Password = PasswordTextBox.Text;
var connString = Connection.ConnectionString;
```

However, recently I have been getting warnings about making these "simplified". This is the simplified version:

```
var Connection = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
    {
        DataSource = ServerNameTextBox.Text,
        InitialCatalog = DatabaseTextbox.Text,
        UserID = UserNameTextBox.Text,
        Password = PasswordTextBox.Text
    };
var connString = Connection.ConnectionString;
```

I assume that the only difference is that it is saving writing time. My question is kind of two parts

- First, which connection string builder is preferable?
- Second, what is the difference in the code? Is either one more efficient?

Comment: I like the second but it is more a matter of preference.  I would use lowercase for connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are syntactically equivalent, so choose whichever you prefer, however the second one is more idiomatic than the first.

As Paparazzi mentioned, you should use lower case for the first letter on your `Connection` variable; in idiomatic C#, only classes, property names, names of structs, and enums should start with an upper case letter.

**Updated**: added additional notes on what should be capitalized

Comment: Classes, property names, names of structs and enums should all be PascalCase.

Comment: updated my response